# Azure website not refreshing after publish from Visual Studio

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2015, iisnode

I am building Node.JS app which has some views and lot of public REST APIs. whenever I make changes to my JS files(controllers or routes) where I write business logic and try to publish them, the Visual studio wizard shows correct diff and after publish is over I can see modified files on server file system (using Kudu debug console) but when I hit the API using POSTMAN I see old response. I tried sending request with **Cache-Control: no-cache** header also but the same response.

But when I stop and start the service again I start getting updated response based on my latest code. Looks like Azure website or iisnode cache code which is running, any idea how to avoid/bust that cache so that immediately after publish I can execute latest code and restart is not required?

Answer (score 1):

You can automatically recycle the site through IISNode using the `watchedFiles` attribute on the *iisnode* element in your `web.config` file.

> **watchedFiles**: semi-colon separated list of files that will be watched
>   for changes to restart the server.

For example, the following *iisnode* element from Web.config that will recycle the site whenever the **web.config** changes or any **.js** files in the top level folder of the app.

```
<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>
```

For more information, you can refer to https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Using-a-custom-web.config-for-Node-apps.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron for these details but I already have `<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js;routes\*.js;views\*.jade" loggingEnabled="true" devErrorsEnabled="true" nodeProcessCommandLine="node.exe --debug" />` in my Web.config file and my changes to js files in root and routes directory are still not getting refreshed.

Comment: This worked for me. I included the folder that wasn't updating in hte iisnode tag on web.config. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on an Azure Web App: 
In VS 2017 right-click on the project and choose Publish.
Click on Configure, as shown below:

[image: Click on Configure]

[image: Check this box]